# Fourier transform of field variables rearrangement

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

I’m working in Peskin and Schroeders book on QFT

These are the Fourier transforms of the field solutions to the Klein-Gordon equation:

[image]

I don’t understand how to get from (2.25) to (2.27)

The logical thing seems to me to try the substitution: $p$ becomes $-p$, for each of the components of the momentum in the second term in the integrand of (2.25), this should however introduce another minus sign in front of the term due to the integration measure. (2.27) lacks this minus sign.

Comment: No. There is no minus sign in the Jacobian.

Comment: The Jacobian would be the negative of the identity matrix in this case, its determinant is negative one

Comment: The substitution $\mathbb{p} \righrarrow -\mathbb{p}$ also swaps the integration borders, to bring them back generates another minus sign that compensates that from the determinant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minus sign that would be produced by the measure can be removed by flipping the integration boundaries:
$$ \int_{-a}^a f(x) \text{d} x \stackrel{x\rightarrow -x}{\longrightarrow} -\int_a^{-a} f(-x) \text{d} x = \int_{-a}^a f(-x) \text{d} x $$